# How to append to an empty numpy ndarray in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I derive sum 2darrays of shape (1,9) in a loop. How do I append them all into one ndarray?

```
mean_array = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 9))

print(mean_array.shape)

for split_array in np.asarray(split_rows):
    split_mean_array = split_array.mean(axis=0)
    print(split_mean_array[:, np.newaxis].T.shape) //prints (1, 9)
    **// This is my derived 2d array split_mean_array[:, np.newaxis].T that I want to be 
    appended**

    //I tried both the below ways, but the if I print mean_array it's all zeroes.
    #np.vstack([mean_array, split_mean_array[:, np.newaxis].T])
    #np.append(mean_array, split_mean_array[:, np.newaxis].T, axis=1)
```

Is the mean_array size declared wrong?
Or am I not understanding how to append to ndarrays correctly. Please help.

Example:
If I get dervided 2d arrays like this in every iteration, [[1 -3 0.2 0 -0 -0.8
  -0.4 -0.1 0]], how do I append them to mean_array?

Comment: Right, you don't understand append to arrays.  It is not a clone of list append.  (re)read the docs.  For a start the concept of `empty` array is very different.  Generally, though, we recommend collecting values in a list with list append, and doing one `vstack` or other concatenate at the end.  Don't concatenate iteratively.

Comment: I see. Thank you, I will collect into list and stack in the end.

Comment: What is the type of `split_rows`? Can you provide some more context for this?

Comment: It is a List. I have to do a mean of all column values, hence converted to array to use mean function